# Checking input of classes in Python

Tags: python, class

I'm very new to Python and programming in general. Right now I am fiddling with classes to get down the basic concepts down.

The code so far:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return '[Person: %s, Age: %s]' % (self.name,self.age)
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,salary,jobs):
        self.salary=salary
        self.jobs= []
        Person.__init__(self,name,age)
```

Really simple so far.. anyway, what would be the best way to make sure that the user enter a two word string for name, an int for age, an int for salary, and a list of words for jobs? Should I use regular expressions for this? Or perhaps a try/exception block? Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you're asking. As you indicated, regular expressions could work- although they might be a bit overkill for your example here.

Instead, you could `try` to cast a `user_input` to the type you want, and `except` to handle errors:

```
try:
  self.age = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
  print "You didn't enter a number for age, try again"
```

Assuming `user_input` is a string; if it is a string with only numbers (eg. '25'), then `int()` will convert it to an int without a hitch, and you will have `self.age = 25`. If it is a string (eg. 'twenty-five'), it will throw a ValueError and you can do whatever you want (display an error message, ask the user to input something again, etc.).

That will give you a very basic way of checking the input; depending on your requirements, you might want more. For example, you may want to enforce bounds on `self.age` (eg. more than 18, less than 99), which you could do with simple `if` statements.

To check that the user has given a list of words for jobs, you could use the `split()` method, which splits a string of words with a given seperator and returns an array of the words. So for instance, if `user_input` is `'engineer janitor'`, `user_input.split()` will return `['engineer', 'janitor']`.

```
>>> user_input = 'engineer janitor'
>>> user_input.split()
['engineer', 'janitor']
```

(remember that `split()` takes an optional argument, which is what string to split on. So if you wanted the user to seperate jobs with commas, you would call `user_input.split(',')`)

You can then use the `len()` function to ensure that the user has entered more than 2 jobs.

```
>>> jobs = user_input.split()
>>> len(jobs)
2
```

For more complex checks (for example, if you want to make sure that the words in the list of jobs are all capitalized, and more than 2 letters long) then yes, regular expressions are likely what you want, but they can be a bit overwhelming if you're just starting with Python :)

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if a string is of length you can use:
   Split the name using split. `ls=name.split(" ")`

   Now check the length of `ls` by `len(ls)`

   If its 2 then way 2 go!!
2. To check if a variable `var` is int or not check its type:

   `print type(var)`

You can use type to check any `class` either custom or already defined.
More info here [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)